# Virtual Neutral in BLDC motor controller

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I don't understand the concept of the "virtual neutral" point that's commonly used in BLDC motor controllers. I understand that it's a proxy for the back emf relative to the true neutral point of the motor, but I don't understand why it's accurate or why it works.

Consider the schematic shown below:

[image]

Here, the back emf of phase 1 is a trapezoidal function that's generated by sources V8 and V9.

The virtual neutral point is created by the resistor summing network of R2, R3 and R4.

If I perform the standard zero crossing checks of V(p1) > V(V_NEUTRAL_VIRT) and V(p1) < V(V_NEUTRAL_VIRT) then the switching does occur at the correct time for the motor RPM.

My confusion is coming from the fact that V_NEUTRAL_VIRT = V(p1) + V(p2) + V(p3) (or at least some factor of the 3 phase voltages) where V(p1) includes the back emf of the undriven phase. If that's compared to V(p1) then I don't follow how this correctly picks up the zero crossing points.

So my question is what is the justification for building the controller in such a way? I don't dispute that works, I just don't understand why it works.

Comment: It's not always virtual. Imagine that the three coils are star-connected. You get three wires out of the motor, and there is the central point inside- you can't access it, but it's there. In a triangle connection it's virtual indeed, but electrically, when you look from outside, you can't tell the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order todo that you need to make some assumption.
Give motor phase U,V,W which we give power through U and V as shown.
[image]

In this case the real netral point will have voltage of \$V_M/2\$ by the voltage divider effect on winding resistant. we can simplify the circuit futhermore by
[image]

As the motor winding haver very small resitance campare to resistor in virtual ground, so we can ignore them.
[image]
From this simplified model you see the virtual nuetral voltage will equals to actual only if \$V_{EMF} = 0\$ and from voltage divider,
$$V_{VN} = \frac{1}{3} V_{EMF} + V_N$$
Event it not equals but it suitable for zero crossing detection because when we measure \$V_{SENSE}\$ respect to \$V_{VN}\$ it will have same sign as \$V_{EMF}\$ and will equals to zero as \$V_{EMF} = 0\$

Note: The property I've used derive from equivalent of resistor circuit which I thought very useful for analyse this kind of problem.
[image]